# Plotting multiple legends

Tags: r

How can I manage to plot multiple legends with a single statement?
Example:

```
start <- seq(20,35, 5)
end <- seq(39,42, 1)
y <- seq(1,4,1)
name <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
plot(1, xlim=c(5,50), ylim=c(0,5))
rect(start, y, end, 1.1:4.1, col="black")
legend(end[1],y[1], name[1], xjust=0, yjust=0.5)
legend(end[2],y[2], name[2], xjust=0, yjust=0.5)
legend(end[3],y[3], name[3], xjust=0, yjust=0.5)
legend(end[4],y[4], name[4], xjust=0, yjust=0.5)
```

The last four lines should be merged into a single command.
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Hmm, legend can do multiple lines so I wonder if you are trying to abuse legend to give you what you want. If the figure produced by your code is really similar to what you want, you could achieve that with `text()` and `rect()`.

Comment: oh, that's easy! thanks very much for the text-advice!

Comment: Just FWIW, since `legend` is designed to draw a bunch of info inside a box, it is possible to have multiple legend boxes in different places on the graph, but each requires its own line of code.  (This is OT - it's not the layout user[randomnmber] was looking for)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop using an index in the range `1:4` (1 to the length of both `end` and `y`). This can be achieved using a `for` loop, or more in R style using `sapply`:

```
sapply(seq_along(y), function(i) {
   legend(end[i],y[i], name[i], xjust=0, yjust=0.5)
 })
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer a little bit. It is technically correct, but the OP might not have any idea what you are doing. I edited some more details in btw.