# add multiple legends to a heatmap in R

Tags: r, plot, legend, heatmap

My question is that I want to add the categorical variables' legends onto the graph but somehow when I used "topright", it did not work for me (see the image below). Basically my idea is to fill the blank area with the legends for my categorical variables on the side of the heatmap. My codes look like

```
heatmap.3(performance, Colv =NA,RowSideColors=row_annotation,col=my_palette)

par(lend = 1)           # square line ends for the color legend
legend("topright",      # location of the legend on the heatmap plot
       legend = c("category1", "category2", "category3"), # category labels
       col = c("gray", "blue", "black"),  # color key
       lty= 1,             # line style
       lwd = 10            # line width
      )
```

Also I want to put multiple legend onto the plot but don't know how to specify their positions using x and y as there are no coordinates in my plot.

Thank you so much!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix to your problem would be to use the option `inset=#` (where # is some floating point number with a comma after it) following your `"topright"` specification after its respective comma, which would indicate how to place your legend relative to your graph.

Instead of specifying the default position `"topright"`, perhaps you may want to try restructuring your code in a more personally customized manner, namely utilizing an x-y axis approach, such as for instance use :

```
dev.new(xpos=#,ypos=#)
```

Or you may also consider using:

```
legend.position=c(#,#)
```

Try these options, even though you say you have no access to coordinates, which is rare for graphical utilities in R, but may well be a future edit to `heatmap.3`. You could also use a fancy R utility called `locator(1)` to point and click with your mouse where you want to see your legend.

In general, the legend option is formally defined as:

```
legend(location, title, legend, ...)
```

If you have any more questions about the legend utility in R, please type in `help(legend)` in your R command line (in R Studio, for instance, if you use that).

To address your question on multiple legends, please consult: [Plotting multiple legends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396194/plotting-multiple-legends)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! @XYZ927 However, I still have a hard time figuring out the specification of x and y coordinates. I tried inset it did not help very much. Could you be more specific about the position? Thanks!

Comment: In order to help you more specifically, the community needs to be able to reliably reproduce the code generating your graphic display from the code that you supply in your question. I have installed the GMD package and put the `require("GMD")` command before running your code to activate the `heatmap.3` command, however, I receive an error when I run the first line of your code `argument 4 matches multiple formal arguments`  Please edit the code in your question above to reliably reproduce the graphic that you generate.

Comment: hi @xyz927 actually the 'my_palette' in the argument 4 `col=my_palette` was generated by myself as I want to change their default color scale. you can delete that argument if you want to reproduce the result. Thanks again!

Comment: @MYjx You're welcome. Please do not forget to upvote users' answers/comments if you believe they add value to SO or are helpful to you or someone with a similar question. Running `heatmap.3(performance, Colv=NA, RowSideColors=row_annotation)` produces another error: `object 'performance' not found`